# What do I do when the keyboard is frozen on my lock screen and I can't get in?

Tags: lock-screens, keyboard

I have an Android Galaxy J7 V and I don't use the key board to put in my password, I just have to swipe a certain way on the dots which I can't see to get into my phone.Since the keyboard is frozen I don't know what to do.

Comment: Restart your phone

Answer (score 0):

What do you call that protection feature. Password but you use swipe to unlock or a feature similar to LG's 'Knock On'

Comment: I don't have a protection feature on my phone where you can just swipe, you have to swipe to enter the combination on the dots if that's what you mean.Since the keyboard is frozen in place, I cant see the combination lock, but thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you could manage to get another input application you could surely manage to switch to it in order to get that obscuring keyboard in the lockscreen. Alternatively if the phone has a custom recovery installed, you can delete that keyboard from `/system/app/SamsungKeyboard` by using TWRP file manager so as to unlock the phone first before you look for another Keyboard app. Consequently, using a third risky way, you can move the app `/system/priv-app/SystemUI/SystemUI.apk` to sdcard using TWRP and boot the phone. It will show no Lockscreen install alternative keyboard app and return that app back to where it was. This will allow you to have a non freezing app and gain access to the swipe to unlock. If incase you don't have TWRP and root, it sounds to me like you have to reset the phone by powering it on using this key combo. Power, Volume Up + Home Button and reset the phone from there. But never forget that Android 6 Marshmallow and above has Factory Reset Protection. If you don't remember the Primary Google Email logged in to the device, never try resetting from recovery since it will request them upon powering on again.